# Jquery Data function returns undefined value when an element is explicitly named in the paremeters

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jquery's "[data](http://api.jquery.com/data/)" function to store some information associated with an HTML element. When this element is explicitly referenced throughout the function, the function returns undefined, however when I bind the element to a variable the function works just fine.

Please check out this example below:

This one works (http://jsfiddle.net/sdbA5/):

```
  $(function() {

    var div = $("#officerBob");

    jQuery.data( div, {
      arrests: 16
    });

    div.click(function(){
       alert("Bob has " + jQuery.data( div ).arrests + " arrests");
    });

});
```

and this one doesn't (http://jsfiddle.net/5Y6b8/1/):

```
  $(function() {

    //var div = $("#officerBob");

    jQuery.data( $("#officerBob"), {
      arrests: 16
    });

    $("#officerBob").click(function(){
       alert("Bob has " + jQuery.data( $("#officerBob") ).arrests + " arrests");
    });

});
```

Comment: why are you not doing it like `var div = $("#foo"); div.data("xxx",123); console.log(div.data("xxx"));`

Comment: That's a really nice syntax, thanks for sharing. I'm not really interested in solving this problem, I'm more interested in understanding why the second code snippet doesn't work, in order to better my understanding of jquery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`jQuery.data()` is supposed to be working off DOM nodes and not jQuery collections.

Changing your code to use a DOM node and it will start working

```
$(function() {

    jQuery.data( $("#officerBob")[0], {
      arrests: 16
    });

    $("#officerBob").click(function(){
       alert("Bob has " + jQuery.data( $("#officerBob")[0] ).arrests + " arrests");
       alert("Bob has " + jQuery.data( this ).arrests + " arrests");
    });

});
```

Now why would the first one work? Because it is working off the same object. In the second one, it is a new jQuery object which is not the same as the first one that was assigned.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, this really cleared things up for me.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not exactly sure why this is so, but all of the jQuery documentation shows the jQuery objects written as variables before they are passed as parameters in functions.

See: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/jquery-object/

I'm just learning more about JavaScript, but I have a feeling that the jQuery object itself `$("#officerBob")` is essentially a function. Your code, which utilizes the **output** of that function, is not expecting a function as an input. It is expecting an object.

So, once you encapsulate the output as an object, (by creating an object whose value is equal to the function's output) your code works.